# Unable to deploy web application to tomcat7 on debian virtual server

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlets, jersey, tomcat7

I am writing simple Java backend using jersey and I want to deploy it to a virtual server, running Debian. I think, I have `tomcat7` installed properly together with `tomcat7-admin` and also set the user roles correctly (`manager-gui` and `manager-script`).

I can see tomcat running, when I visit `http://my-ip-address:8080`. I also can access manager through `http://my-ip-address:8080/manager/html`, so I think the tomcat is configured properly.

The problem is that when I want to deploy my web application (using `tomcat7-maven-plugin`), the deployment itself doesn't work. here is trace from maven:

```
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /parser
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29.826s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Aug 28 11:50:07 CEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/97M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is also the content of catalina log about the thing:

```
Aug 28, 2016 11:49:29 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/parser]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Aug 28, 2016 11:49:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/parser]
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/parser.war
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/parser/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-el-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/parser/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/parser/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.47.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getServletContainerInitializer
SEVERE: The ServletContentInitializer [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci] could not be created
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1233)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5209)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1003)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processServletContainerInitializers
SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/parser/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/parser]
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext  startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Aug 28, 2016 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/parser] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I have no idea what errors above means, because I was able to deploy this app to my local tomcat using idea (not maven-tomcat-plugin). I will try to provide as many information as needed, because I need to fix this rather quickly.

I read some threads about similar failures and there, the solution was to set the scope of `javax.servlet-api` to `provided`. In my `pom.xml` I didn't have this dependency, as `jersey-servlet` already has it as provided, so I have no other ideas on how to fix this.

Here is my actual pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.tryit</groupId>
    <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>parser</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.version>1.0.3</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>parser</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>parser</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/parser</path>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>pwd</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.rx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-rx-client-rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Do you have any idea, how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `tomcat7-maven-plugin` in plugins not in dependencies see the [usage](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) page. Remove from dependencies and try

Comment: What a silly mistake of mine. I probably left that in dependencies while I was trying some time ago, because I got them in both dependencies and plugins. OK, this solved my problem, that was not even a real problem. Thanks for your good eye.